# How can I install a python package without pip or virtualenv

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have to deploy a python application to a production server (Ubuntu) that I do not control nor do I have permissions to `apt-get, pip, virtualenv,` etc. Currently, its the server is running python 2.6+. I need to install `pycrypto` as a dependency for the application but given my limited permissions, I'm not sure as to how to do it. The only think I have permissions to do is `wget` a resource and unpack it or things along those lines.

First off, is it possible to use it without getting it installed in the aforementioned approach? If not, could I download the package then drop in `__init__.py` files in the pycrypto dir so python knows how to find it like so:

```
/my_app
  /pycrypto
     /__init__.py
     /pycrypto.py
```

Comment: you could try  putting it in your PYTHONPATH .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [PEP370](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/), starting with *python 2.6* you can have a per-user site directory (see the [What's new in Python 2.6?](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-370-per-user-site-packages-directory)).

So you can use the `--user` option of `easy_install` to install the directory for each user instead of system-wide. I believe a similar option exists for `pip` too.
This doesn't require any privileges since it only uses current user directories.

If you don't have any installer installed you can manually unpack the package into:

```
~/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

Or, if you are on Windows, into:

```
%APPDATA%/Python/Python26/site-packages
```

---

In the case of `pycrypto`, the package requires *building* before installation because it contains some C code. The sources should contain a `setup.py` file. You have to build the library running

```
python setup.py build
```

Afterwards you can install it in the user directory by giving:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

Note that the building phase might require some C library to already be installed.

---

If you don't want to do this, the *only* option is to ship the library together with your application.

---

By the way: I believe `easy_install` doesn't really check whether you are root before performing a system wide install. It simply checks whether it can write in the system-wide site directory. So, if you do have the privileges to write there, there's no need to use `sudo` in the first place. However this would be really odd...

Comment: Looks like I don't have easy_install either which sucks.  So to be clear, when you say shipping the library with my app, you mean in a manner that I listed in the question or another way?

Comment: @Brad I just updated my answer. You just have to copy the package in the per-user site directory. See my answer and the linked documentation for in-depth details. Some complex installations would require to modify some `.pth` found, but that is generally easy. If the basic copy/paste doesn't work leave me a comment and I'll check whether `pycrypto` requires a bit of configuration.

Comment: Of course easy_install does check permissions neither does pip   but ubuntu certainly does check.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't see the point of your comment. I simply wanted to clarify that: system install does **not** imply required use of `sudo`. You *can* be able to perform a system install without `sudo` privileges (although that's quite an odd thing to do...)

Comment: I don't get what you mean, if you want to install python packages on ubuntu using pip or easy_install to the default packages directory you need sudo. Basically being able to install system-wide without sudo defeats the purpose of having sudo in the first place.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, that's why I said that it is an odd to do (for an admin). However if someone does `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` *everyone* would be able to perform system-wide installations of python packages.

Comment: @Bakuriu - I'm sorry to be a pain, but i have no .local/lib directory.  python2.6 is being executed from a /usr/bin/python2.6.

Comment: I understand but it may be worth mentioning that along with odd it would also be a very bad idea to change permissions like that.

Comment: @Brad And what's the problem? Create it. Python doesn't create it by default during installation.

Comment: python2.6 is being executed from a /usr/bin/python2.6.  That happens to be a symlink to a dir that I control. /home/my_other_usr/Python2.6 which contains  lib/python2.6/site-packages.  I unpacked the package into that and reran the code but got the same error.  I created what you suggested in your answer but again, same issue.  so now pycrypto lives /home/my_other_usr/Python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pycrypto and here /home/my_usr/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages but neither works.  Would I need to tell python where those files are somehow?

Comment: You have to put the package under the home directory of the user **running** the interpreter, not the user where python is installed.

Comment: @Brad Note that `pycrypto` has to be *built* before installing. The main directory you downloaded should have a `setup.py` file. Run `python setup.py build` inside this directory (building might have some prerequisites...). In fact you can use `python setup.py install --user` so you don't have to manually copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

Use `easy_install`. It should be installed already on Ubuntu for python 2.6+. If not take a look at these install [instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installation-instructions).

Comment: how would you install without sudo?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham is `easy_install` not on the system already?

Comment: you need sudo to install packages in any /usr subdirectories  where I imagine python is installed.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Not if you install just for your user.