# Install​ and​ import​ ssh​tunnel​ library​ with​ raspberrypi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunnel

I want​ to​ access to​ database​ server​ with​ library​ `​sshtunnel`

I​ use​ python. ​I​ can​ import​ ssh​tunnel​ when​ i​ use​ window. If i​ want​ to​ import​ `ssh​tunnel​` with​ raspberry​pi​ how​ should i​ do?

My​ raspberry pi​ can't​ do `pip​ install​ sshtunnel`

Comment: Check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267454/how-can-i-install-a-python-package-without-pip-or-virtualenv

Comment: Interesting! Why don't you install pip?

Comment: My​ raspberry​pi​ can​ use​ command(pip​ install​)​when​ i​ install​ other​ library​.​But​ i​ not​ sure for this library​ so this​ library​ support for​ raspberrypi​ os.

Comment: Its on pypi.org so pip should work

Comment: Thank​ you. This​ success​ with:  python​ -​m​ install​ sshtunnel.